# Spock integration test for Grails controller method using MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, grails, stored-procedures, spock

I have a problem which is probably related to database transaction handling in Spock. The simplified code is:

Grails Controller:

```
def methodA() {
    def input = new X(request.JSON)
    def result = service.methodB( input )
    render text: result as JSON, ...
}
```

Grails Service:

```
def methodB( in ) {
    in.save(flush: true)
    Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    sql.call("{call mysql_procedure(?)}", in.id)
    return in
}
```

The mysql_procedure takes the newly created object, and based on its data, updates other rows in the same table. Everything works just fine, however...

I have written integration test using Spock (test class extends IntegrationSpec)

```
void "test .."() {
    given:
    controller.request.JSON = [ ... value: 'test1' ... ]

    when:
    controller.methodA()
    def result = new JSONObject(controller.response.contentAsString)
    def otherInstance = X.findById( result.otherInstanceId )

    then:
    otherInstance.value == 'test1'
}
```

The value is updated properly during normal operation (sending of proper POST request), but does not work in the tests.

Why test does not see changes done by the procedure?

Comment: What is the output you are getting? Is the methodA in the controller only allowed for specific http methods like POST?

Comment: It is not restricted to POST method. During normal operation I can see that the procedure was run, and it updated every recod properly. However the integration test fails during the 'then' phase, as it does not see the changes made by the procedure.

Comment: ok, but can you post the error you get?

Comment: I do not get any error, just the otherInstance.value is incorrect, as the procedure should set it to 'test1', but its empty string in that case.